# Variables assigned only in class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to assign variables in the class findDist() but once they're assigned and it moves onto closeDist() it says the variables are not assigned.

This is the error: `"NameError: global name 'Dist1' is not defined"`

Here is the code, any solution?

```
n=int(0)
Pro1='alive'
Pro2='alive'
Pro3='alive'
Pro4='alive'
Pro5='alive'
Pro6='alive'
xYou = 1
yYou = 1
xPro1 = 3
yPro1 = 0
xPro2 = 2
yPro2 = 3
xPro3 = 1
yPro3 = 6
xPro4 = 5
yPro4 = 6
xPro5 = 6
yPro5 = 2
xPro6 = 8
yPro6 = 5
proDists = []

def findDist():
    if Pro1 == 'alive':
        Dist1 = (abs(xYou-xPro1)+abs(yYou-yPro1))
        print(Dist1)
    if Pro2 == 'alive':
        Dist2 = (abs(xYou-xPro2)+abs(yYou-yPro2))
        print(Dist2)
    if Pro3 == 'alive':
        Dist3 = (abs(xYou-xPro3)+abs(yYou-yPro3))
        print(Dist3)
    if Pro4 == 'alive':
        Dist4 = (abs(xYou-xPro4)+abs(yYou-yPro4))
        print(Dist4)
    if Pro5 == 'alive':
        Dist5 = (abs(xYou-xPro5)+abs(yYou-yPro5))
        print(Dist5)
    if Pro6 == 'alive':
        Dist6 = (abs(xYou-xPro6)+abs(yYou-yPro6))
        print(Dist6)
    findClose()

def findClose():
    proDists.extend((Dist1,Dist2,Dist3,Dist4,Dist5,Dist6))
    print ("".join(proDists))

findDist()
```

Comment: Global vars... Do you really need them here?

Comment: You haven't got any classes here. You've only got some standalone functions.

Comment: Also, you should look into lists or tuples instead of making lots of variables named *something*1,*something*2, etc.

Comment: Pro tip: there's a rule called "DRY", for "Don't Repeat Yourself".  When you see that you're repeating the same code with only slight variations, that's a sign you need to work at a different level of abstraction.  You know about lists (e.g. `proDists`), so you're partway there -- if you know about `for` loops too, you should be able to see how to modify your code to make it much shorter and simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to send the local variables as parameters from the calling function:

```
def findDist():

    if Pro1 == 'alive':
        Dist1 = (abs(xYou-xPro1)+abs(yYou-yPro1))
        print(Dist1)
    if Pro2 == 'alive':
        Dist2 = (abs(xYou-xPro2)+abs(yYou-yPro2))
        print(Dist2)
    if Pro3 == 'alive':
        Dist3 = (abs(xYou-xPro3)+abs(yYou-yPro3))
        print(Dist3)
    if Pro4 == 'alive':
        Dist4 = (abs(xYou-xPro4)+abs(yYou-yPro4))
        print(Dist4)
    if Pro5 == 'alive':
        Dist5 = (abs(xYou-xPro5)+abs(yYou-yPro5))
        print(Dist5)
    if Pro6 == 'alive':
        Dist6 = (abs(xYou-xPro6)+abs(yYou-yPro6))
        print(Dist6)
    findClose(Dist1, Dist2, Dist3, Dist4, Dist5, Dist6)

def findClose(Dist1, Dist2, Dist3, Dist4, Dist5, Dist6):

    proDists.extend((Dist1,Dist2,Dist3,Dist4,Dist5,Dist6))
    print ("".join(proDists))
```

Comment: Thanks this sorted it!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it easily using the `global` statement..

```
def findDist():
    global Dist1, Dist2, Dist3, Dist4, Dist5, Dist6
```

However it is encouraged to avoid using too much global variables. You can pass them as a parameter to `findClose()` instead, as suggested by karthikr:

```
findClose(Dist1, Dist2, Dist3, Dist4, Dist5, Dist6)
```

and:

```
def findClose(Dist1, Dist2, Dist3, Dist4, Dist5, Dist6):
```

Hope this helps!